# Minipage make different space between tables

Tags: tables, spacing, minipage

I have the following problem. I use a minipage to show two table next to each other. As you can see in the figure the first two rows of the tables are okay, but the thrid has a problem with the distance. So what do I wrong with the code?

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
\hline Algorithm & Avg. Error & Avg. Adjusted Error \\
\hline KNN & x & x \\
\hline WKNN & x & x \\
\hline MAP & x & x \\
\hline MMSE & x & x \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Table gives an overview about the average positioning errors for each algorithm used in the first test.}
\label{tab:overallerror}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{2cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
\hline Floor &~\# Training samples &~\# Test samples \\ 
\hline  0 & 6 & 6 \\ 
\hline  1 & 6 & 6 \\ 
\hline  2 & 7 & 6 \\ 
\hline  3 & 7 & 6 \\ 
\hline  4 & 7 & 6 \\ 
\hline  5 & 8 & 6 \\ 
\hline  6 & 4 & 4 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\captionof{table}{Overview about recorded training and test samples at each floor.}
\label{tab:testtrainingsamples}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
\hline Algorithm & Avg. Error & Avg. Adjusted Error \\
\hline KNN & x & x \\
\hline WKNN & x & x \\
\hline MAP & x & x \\
\hline MMSE & x & x \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Table gives an overview about the average positioning errors for each algorithm used in the second test.}
\label{tab:overallerror_second}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{2cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
\hline Floor &~\# Training samples &~\# Test samples \\ 
\hline 0 & 19 & 7 \\ 
\hline 1 & 4 & 3 \\ 
\hline 2 & 4 & 3 \\ 
\hline 3 & 4 & 3 \\ 
\hline 4 & 4 & 3 \\ 
\hline 5 & 4 & 3 \\ 
\hline 6 & 4 & 2 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\captionof{table}{Table shows the number of training and test data recorded for each floor. }
\label{tab:dataovereachfloor_secondrun}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
\hline Algorithm & Avg. Error & Avg. Adjusted Error \\
\hline KNN & x & x \\
\hline WKNN & x & x \\
\hline MAP & x & x \\
\hline MMSE & x & x \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Table gives an overview about the average positioning errors for each algorithm used in the second test.}
\label{tab:overallerror_third}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{2cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
\hline Floor &~\# Training samples &~\# Test samples \\ 
\hline 0 & 6 & 2 \\ 
\hline 1 & 6 & 2 \\ 
\hline 2 & 6 & 2 \\ 
\hline 3 & 6 & 2 \\ 
\hline 4 & 6 & 2 \\ 
\hline 5 & 6 & 2 \\ 
\hline 6 & 4 & 2 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\captionof{table}{Table shows the number of training and test data recorded for each floor. }
\label{tab:dataovereachfloor_thirdrun}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Could you please make your code in to a complete MWE including `\documentclass` and an appropriate premable showing the packages you use.

Comment: You don't break the line, all tables form one line which latex breaks where it can and adjust to right margin except for last line. If you break lines where you want, all tables will align vertically. Add \\ after every second minipage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were two problems.  One, Ignasi mentioned, which is that you did not line break or `\par`after each set of two tabulars.  The other problem is that you had 5, not 3 nor 6 `\hspace` macros.  I removed the two that you had at the beginning of lines, leaving only the 3 that occurred mid line.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{caption}
\textwidth 6.5in
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
\hline Algorithm & Avg. Error & Avg. Adjusted Error \\
\hline KNN & x & x \\
\hline WKNN & x & x \\
\hline MAP & x & x \\
\hline MMSE & x & x \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Table gives an overview about the average positioning errors for each algorithm used in the first test.}
\label{tab:overallerror}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{2cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
\hline Floor &~\# Training samples &~\# Test samples \\ 
\hline  0 & 6 & 6 \\ 
\hline  1 & 6 & 6 \\ 
\hline  2 & 7 & 6 \\ 
\hline  3 & 7 & 6 \\ 
\hline  4 & 7 & 6 \\ 
\hline  5 & 8 & 6 \\ 
\hline  6 & 4 & 4 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\captionof{table}{Overview about recorded training and test samples at each floor.}
\label{tab:testtrainingsamples}
\end{minipage}\par
%\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
\hline Algorithm & Avg. Error & Avg. Adjusted Error \\
\hline KNN & x & x \\
\hline WKNN & x & x \\
\hline MAP & x & x \\
\hline MMSE & x & x \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Table gives an overview about the average positioning errors for each algorithm used in the second test.}
\label{tab:overallerror_second}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{2cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
\hline Floor &~\# Training samples &~\# Test samples \\ 
\hline 0 & 19 & 7 \\ 
\hline 1 & 4 & 3 \\ 
\hline 2 & 4 & 3 \\ 
\hline 3 & 4 & 3 \\ 
\hline 4 & 4 & 3 \\ 
\hline 5 & 4 & 3 \\ 
\hline 6 & 4 & 2 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\captionof{table}{Table shows the number of training and test data recorded for each floor. }
\label{tab:dataovereachfloor_secondrun}
\end{minipage}\par
%\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
\hline Algorithm & Avg. Error & Avg. Adjusted Error \\
\hline KNN & x & x \\
\hline WKNN & x & x \\
\hline MAP & x & x \\
\hline MMSE & x & x \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Table gives an overview about the average positioning errors for each algorithm used in the second test.}
\label{tab:overallerror_third}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{2cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
\hline Floor &~\# Training samples &~\# Test samples \\ 
\hline 0 & 6 & 2 \\ 
\hline 1 & 6 & 2 \\ 
\hline 2 & 6 & 2 \\ 
\hline 3 & 6 & 2 \\ 
\hline 4 & 6 & 2 \\ 
\hline 5 & 6 & 2 \\ 
\hline 6 & 4 & 2 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\captionof{table}{Table shows the number of training and test data recorded for each floor. }
\label{tab:dataovereachfloor_thirdrun}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're missing `%` after `\hspace{0.5cm}`

Answer (score 2):

A solution using the `floatrow` package – and `makecell`to improve the appearance of  column heads: each row of tables is in a `floatrow` environment; defined by a `\tabbox{the table itself}{\caption{…}\label…}}` command. No need for a `\captionof` command

```
        \documentclass[11pt,  a4paper]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
        \usepackage{lmodern} 

        \usepackage[textwidth = 16cm]{geometry} 

       \usepackage{floatrow}
       \DeclareFloatVCode{somespace}{\vspace{1.667\baselineskip}}
        \usepackage{caption, subcaption}
        \usepackage{makecell}

        \begin{document}

        \begin{table}[!h]
        \captionsetup{font = small}
        \floatsetup{rowpostcode =somespace}
        \begin{floatrow}
        %
        \ttabbox{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
        \hline \thead{Algorithm} & \thead{Avg. Error} & \thead{Avg. \\Adjusted Error} \\
        \hline KNN & x & x \\
        \hline WKNN & x & x \\
        \hline MAP & x & x \\
        \hline MMSE & x & x \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}}%
        {\caption{Table gives an overview about the average positioning errors for each algorithm used in the first test.}
        \label{tab:overallerror}}%
        %
        \ttabbox{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|p{2cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
        \hline \thead{Floor} &\thead{\# Training\\ samples} &\thead{\# Test\\ samples} \\
        \hline  0 & 6 & 6 \\
        \hline  1 & 6 & 6 \\
        \hline  2 & 7 & 6 \\
        \hline  3 & 7 & 6 \\
        \hline  4 & 7 & 6 \\
        \hline  5 & 8 & 6 \\
        \hline  6 & 4 & 4 \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}}%
        {\caption{Overview about recorded training and test samples at each floor.}
        \label{tab:testtrainingsamples}}%
        \end{floatrow}
        %\vspace{2\baselineskip}%
        \begin{floatrow}
        \ttabbox{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
        \hline \thead{Algorithm} & \thead{Avg. Error}& \thead{Avg.\\ Adjusted Error} \\
        \hline KNN & x & x \\
        \hline WKNN & x & x \\
        \hline MAP & x & x \\
        \hline MMSE & x & x \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}}%
        {\caption{Table gives an overview about the average positioning errors for each algorithm used in the second test.}
        \label{tab:overallerror_second}}%
        %
        \ttabbox{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|p{2cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
        \hline \thead{Floor} &\thead{\# Training\\ samples} &\thead{\# Test\\ samples} \\
        \hline 0 & 19 & 7 \\
        \hline 1 & 4 & 3 \\
        \hline 2 & 4 & 3 \\
        \hline 3 & 4 & 3 \\
        \hline 4 & 4 & 3 \\
        \hline 5 & 4 & 3 \\
        \hline 6 & 4 & 2 \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}}%
        {\caption{Table shows the number of training and test data recorded for each floor. }
        \label{tab:dataovereachfloor_secondrun}}%
        \end{floatrow}
        %\vspace{2\baselineskip}%
        %
        \begin{floatrow}
        \ttabbox{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
        \hline \thead{Algorithm} & \thead{Avg. Error}& \thead{Avg.\\ Adjusted Error} \\
        \hline KNN & x & x \\
        \hline WKNN & x & x \\
        \hline MAP & x & x \\
        \hline MMSE & x & x \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}}%
        {\caption{Table gives an overview about the average positioning errors for each algorithm used in the second test.}
        \label{tab:overallerror_third}}%
        %
        \ttabbox{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|p{2cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
        \hline \thead{Floor} &\thead{\# Training\\ samples} &\thead{\# Test\\ samples} \\
        \hline 0 & 6 & 2 \\
        \hline 1 & 6 & 2 \\
        \hline 2 & 6 & 2 \\
        \hline 3 & 6 & 2 \\
        \hline 4 & 6 & 2 \\
        \hline 5 & 6 & 2 \\
        \hline 6 & 4 & 2 \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}}%
        {\caption{Table shows the number of training and test data recorded for each floor. }
        \label{tab:dataovereachfloor_thirdrun}}%
        \end{floatrow}
        \end{table}

        \end{document}
```

[image]